# How to get number of occurrence of a childtag attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript

following is my jsp page.

```
<div id="document-wrapper" class="document-wrapper">
  <div class="document">
          <p class="Normal DocDefaults " style="background-color:#9ee0b8" data-type="question">text</p>

          <p class="Normal DocDefaults " style="text-align: justify;border-color: #FFFFFF; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;background-color: #FFFFFF;margin-bottom: 3mm;line-height: 218%;" data-type="question">another text</p>
          <p class="Normal DocDefaults ">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the number of occurance of data-type="question" in

tag.
i tried find and attribute properties of js but couldnt print the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find all of those elements within the element with the `document-wrapper` class:

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.document-wrapper [data-type="question"]');
console.log(els.length);
```

```html
<div id="document-wrapper" class="document-wrapper">
  <div class="document">
    <p class="Normal DocDefaults " style="background-color:#9ee0b8" data-type="question">text</p>
    <p class="Normal DocDefaults " style="text-align: justify;border-color: #FFFFFF; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;background-color: #FFFFFF;margin-bottom: 3mm;line-height: 218%;" data-type="question">another text</p>
    <p class="Normal DocDefaults ">&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```